# Battery drain with higher volume

Tags: power, bluetooth, speakers

I was wondering if a Device connected to a speaker via Bluetooth drains more energy while sending high volume compared to the same sound on low volume. This might not be the perfect question for this forum as there might be a more computational aspect.

Comment: The output on the speaker shouldn't matter as I am interested in the battery of the device sending the audio stream. Guess that wasn't that clear.

Comment: @Arsenal: I'd be careful when equating less transmit data to lower power usage. Different codecs have different complexity when compressing for different target compressions. Also, usually, when turning a nicely harmonics-based signal into one limited by quantization, you end up with *more* information (relative to normalized volume), and unless you actually *hide* data in silence.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure if I get your point. You mean encoding the lower volume signal might need more energy than encoding the higher volume signal? Ew that will be hard to estimate. I've added a small test with MP3s in my answer - I know it's a different codec, but I couldn't find a SBC encoder.

Comment: @Arsenal exactly, extremely hard to estimate the power needed during compression. So thanks for the testing! Bluez (the stock linux bluetooth stack) must contain an SBC encoder, but I don't know how "easily" that can be used standalone. Gimme a minute or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Bluetooth is a digital data connection, and it's power does not vary based on the raw amplitude of the audio signal being digitized and transmitted. What would change the battery life  is how much data is being sent, and a volume difference is not that. Additionally,  Bluetooth audio allows for volume control outside of the raw audio signal,  and that also doesn't increase power usage.

Any given audio stream will use the same amount of power as the next really. Bluetooth is not a very power hungry spec.

Answer (score 3):

So if you had just a raw audio stream, you would need an equal amount of bytes for each audio sample. Regardless of the volume of the audio. For a transmission the actual content of the bytes doesn't really matter, just the number of bytes dictate how much transmissions are needed.

In that case lowering the volume would do nothing to reduce the needed amount of transmissions and as such the energy needed would stay the same.

But Bluetooth uses a lossy compression for audio transmission (except the aptX lossless profile if I'm not mistaken). So in this case the audio might be better compressible if the volume is lower (the signal won't change as much as before). This would mean less bytes need to be transmitted and reduce the amount of energy needed to transmit the audio.

Of course you will loose dynamic range in doing so and the audio quality will drop.

You could try this using a sample audio stream, compress it with A2DP (standard Bluetooth codec) reduce the volume and compress it again and have a look if the file size decreased.

Reducing the sample rate and the dynamic range will of course help greatly in reducing the amount of bytes needed - but comes with a loss in audio quality. You should consider the quality of the listening equipment, if it's some cheap headphone or speaker, you might not even notice.

---

Edit: I tried to see an effect of volume on file size using MP3 encoding (a SBC encoder is quite difficult to get as it seems). Using a fixed bitrate results of course in same file sizes no matter the volume (similar to an uncompressed stream). Compressing with a variable bitrate however showed some reduction:

I was using the song 12 juin 3049 by Caravan Palace, using Audacity with LAME v.3.99.3, variable bitrate and a quality setting of 5.

- Original volume (0 dB): 3 461 120 bytes
- Normalized to -6 dB: 3 362 816 bytes (-3 %)
- Normalized to -24 dB: 2 883 584 bytes (-16 %)

So there might be some savings if you reduce the volume before it going into the encoder. Don't know if it is worth the hassle and if the preprocessing costs more energy than just sending the bytes.

Comment: I did some googling just now, and found that A2DP is often used in conjunction with AVRCP, which allows an absolute volume value to be transmitted along with the audio stream. So my guess is that in many cases, the stream is always sent at 100% volume, and the receiving device adjusts the output gain according to the absolute volume value from the sending device.

Comment: @Dampmaskin yeah, pretty much like a volume knob on the speaker.  But it doesn't touch the stream at all, if it is at 50% it stays there. (at least that's how I understood [this](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=119996) specification)

Comment: @Arsenal have an SBC encoder at hand, so if you've got me some uncompressed audio, I can give you some compression gains

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess you could download a song from [here](https://archive.org/details/machina.II.ver.SPIFC) Smashing Pumpkins released an album under CC-license. You don't have to listen to it ;-)